# SQL Server 2017 Backup strategy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup

RTO is 8 hours

RPO is 24 hours

Retention Period: 5 days

Based on above values I have plan to configure below backup stratgey for Production. Please suggest if there is any changes required in below backup policy.

Full Backup - Daily

Log Backup - every 30 minutes (this is just to prevent log grwoth/low disk problems during index rebuild job)

SQL DB size is approx 500-650 GB.

HA/DR solution for above DB: Configured Distributed Always-ON AG from DC1 to DC2 on top of WSFC (DC1- two DB serevrs and DC2-two DB servers)

Comment: I do not see any issue in the approach. The other cost saving option is, since you have 24 hrs RPO. keep DB in simple recovery and take daily full backup. Copy this full backup to other DC and in case of disaster restore the backup and point the app to other DC or if you already have app their then things are more easy. This will save you hassle of Dist AG

Comment: Just to be sure, you mentionned that you use a distibuted AG so you have an AG with 2 node on your DC1 and an AG with 2 nodes on your DC2 with a distributed AG that link both. What do you mean by "on top of a WSFC" ? If you only have 2 server in your DC1, they cannot be in an AG and also in cluster... Did you mean on top of WSFC because you created a cluster for your AG ?

Answer (score 0):

To start with I do not see any technical issue in your current approach. If I may suggest and if it suits your requirement, since your RPO is 24 hours keep DB in simple recovery take daily full backup and every 8 hours diff backup(optional). The diff backup is not even required but just to give you some restore point in between. Now store these backups locally and also on different server in other DC.

Copy these backup files on different SQL Server in other DC and restore it. So now you have always have a complete data which is less than 24 hours new in other DC. This will meet your RPO but yes you should *test this* to see if that meets your RTO of 8 hours or not.

The advantage with this approach is its very simple configuration, saves licensing cost of few Windows server. You dont have to worry about complexity of AG, even a new DBA and junior DBA's can work on it easily, etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

As your database is part of an availability group, you cannot change the recovery model to simple. AG needs full recovery.

Having those log backup also provide a second option in case your daily full backup is not good and cannot be restorable (you can restore the previous full backup and all the log backup, which I guess can be done within your 8 hrs RTO).
You also have the automatic page repair provided by the AG against corruption but if ever there was a case of corruption that cannot be automatically fix, your log backup should get you cover.

You could check for Diff backup daily and Full backup weekly (or bi-weekly). In some cases, it could save some space as diff backup usually are smaller then full (unless there is a lot of modification done to the data).

If you take the backup only in your DC1, then have a copy of those backup to your DC2.

With those RPO, you could also run backup on your secondary DC.

Those are not agressive SLA so you have a lot of options. Maybe you don't need the complexity of a distributed AG and you may not need high availability either...